# How to set a jspinner max value from a variable?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a few `jspinners`, they are: `min char`, `max cha`r, `min low char`, `min up chars` etc.
Now I need to set the max values of `min low char`, `min up char`, etc, to the `max chars`, but `jspinner` models dont allow any variables to set any model value. so how can what can I do to set the max values of those spinners to the value of `max char`.

Answer (score 3):

The SpinnerNumberModel has setMaximum and setMinimum methods.  You could ask the spinner for it's model, and if it's an instanceof SpinnerNumberModel cast it.

Otherwise, you could maintain a reference to the original models used to populate the spinners in the first place and update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `getMaximum` with an anonymous model class to make it reference a member of the parent type. E.g.

```
JSpinner minChar = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel() {
  @Override
  public Comparable<Integer> getMaximum() {
    return maximum;
  }
});
```